# NullPointerException happens in an Android code snippet

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Here's the code which deals with member registration.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, email, password);
                 } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "register");
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    }
```

When I run the code, it throws a `NullPointerException`, showing the following logs.

> 07-03 16:13:33.061  24078-24078/com.marshall.gruppo E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: **main Process: com.marshall.gruppo, PID: 24078
>           java.lang.NullPointerException**
>               at com.marshall.gruppo.ui.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:184)
>               at com.marshall.gruppo.ui.RegisterActivity.access$300(RegisterActivity.java:31)
>               at com.marshall.gruppo.ui.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:80)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

According to the log, the snippet that seems to have the problem is:

> AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

Which is the last line of the `registerUser` method.

What do you think the problem is? If there is any information that you should know further about this code, please let me know.

The `AppController` class is as follows.

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
</application>
```

Comment: did you write `AppController`? If that line is causing a NPE, it means that `getInstance()` is returning null

Comment: @Blackbelt No the method is     public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

Comment: and the mInstance there is a variable from private static AppController mInstance;

Comment: Did you add AppController to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you didn't declare your Subclass of Application to the AndroidManifest. Add   `android:name="path.to.AppController"` to the Application tag, otherwise your subclass of Application is not instantiated and `mInstance` remains not initialized (null by default). And that explains the NPE

```
 <application
    android:name="path.to.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Oh lord! I was missing this critical part. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, AppController is not added to your manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController" //this one
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

So onCreate never get called and mInstance is null.