# java.lang.NullPointerException for ListActivity (MYSQL>PHP>Android (volley))

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I tried to create an applications which use ListActivity to show the mysql database table (For coding please find the tutorial link: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/12/android-php-read-mysql-db-volley.html). But there are two errors appear:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.toby.readdata/com.example.toby.readdata.ReadData}: java.lang.NullPointerException
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
**com.example.toby.readdata.ReadData.ReadDataFromDB(ReadData.java:111)
com.example.toby.readdata.ReadData.onCreate(ReadData.java:56)**
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:79com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ReadData.java:111 refer to MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jreq);
ReadData.java:56 refer to ReadDataFromDB();**

line 111 related code:

```
private void ReadDataFromDB() {
        PD.show();
        JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            int success = response.getInt("success");

                            if (success == 1) {
                                JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("orders");

                                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    item.put(ITEM_ID, jobj.getString(ITEM_ID));
                                    item.put(ITEM_NAME,
                                            jobj.getString(ITEM_NAME));

                                    Item_List.add(item);

                                } // for loop ends

                                String[] from = { ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME };
                                int[] to = { R.id.item_id, R.id.item_name };

                                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                        getApplicationContext(), Item_List,
                                        R.layout.list_items, from, to);

                                setListAdapter(adapter);

                                PD.dismiss();

                            } // if ends

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                PD.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jreq); // <-----line111

    }`
```

line 56 related code as below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    Item_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
    PD.setMessage("Loading.....");
    PD.setCancelable(false);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new ListitemClickListener());

    ReadDataFromDB();  //<-----line56
}
```

`

I have already seen some related solve idea for example 
1. add setContentView
2. change the listview to android.R.id.list
But problem still issue, are there any solution for this case. Thanks.

Comment: did you declare your Application subclass in the manifest ? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209717/nullpointerexception-happens-in-an-android-code-snippet) an example

Comment: Bravo! It works now. I added <android:name=".MyApplication"> into manifest and it works now! One million thanks!